# Use grep to search for words beginning with non-word characters

Tags: linux, text-processing, command-line, grep, search

The contents of the file testing.txt are:

```
ls -a
cmake --verbose
verbose
```

I want to use `grep` to look through this file and find only the word beginning with "--" i.e. the word "--verbose"

However using the following patterns as an argument for `grep` does not work:

```
$ cat testing.txt | grep -- 
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN
   [FILE]... Try 'grep --help' for more information.

$ cat testing.txt | grep -
ls -a
cmake --verbose

$ cat testing.txt | grep '--v'
grep (GNU grep) 3.1
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Mike Haertel and others, see <http://git.sv.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/AUTHORS>.

$ cat testing.txt | grep ver
cmake --verbose
verbose

$ cat testing.txt | grep '-ver'
ls -a
```

- `grep` thinks that all arguments beginning with a `--` are options? How do you prevent this so that grep can search for a pattern (in a file) that begins with "--"?
- the last attempt uses the pattern "-ver" so that `grep` does not think the pattern is an option, but then `grep` does not match the word "--verbose" in the file even though it contains the pattern "-ver". What causes this behavior?

Comment: `grep -Po '\--\w+'` should help you pick your words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string `--` is special for most utilities when it occurs on the command line.  It signals *the end of options* to the command line argument parser.  It is used in situations where you may want to pass a filename that starts with a dash, as in `rm -- -f` (to delete a file called `-f` in the current directory).

To use `--` as a pattern with `grep`, tell the utility explicitly that it is a pattern:

```
grep -e --
```

The `-e` option to `grep` takes an option argument which is the pattern that you want `grep` to search with.

You could also use

```
grep -- --
```

Here, `grep` knows that the second `--` is the pattern, because the first `--` says it can't be an option.

---

Your last pipeline returns `ls -a` because that's a line in the file that does not include an `r`.  The command `grep -ver` may also be written `grep -v -e r`, i.e., "extract all the lines that do not (`-v`) match `r` (`-e r`)".

Comment: Simple answer, was expecting a complicated regular expression so I am pleased with this straight forward solution. Thanks for also adding a use case for the string `--`, it's very useful not just to understand what something is but also when to use it

Comment: can you clarify "The -e option to grep takes an option argument which is the pattern that you want grep to search with. ", do you mean to say "The -e option to grep takes an optional argument which is the pattern that you want grep to search with"?

Comment: @MyWrathAcademia No, not optional. An "option argument" is an argument to an option. The option `-e` takes an argument, its option argument.

Comment: Oh I see, you mean an "option's argument" i.e. an argument that belongs to an option. As for the last pipe containing line, good analysis. It's very interesting because I did not consider that `grep` combined the short options `-v` and `e`, but how come `r` is not taken as an option? Is it because it comes after `e` so `grep` thinks that `r` is an argument to the option `e` even without a space separating them. Shouldn't Linux commands assume only a space separated string is an argument to an option, other wise we get human error as shown here?

Comment: @MyWrathAcademia For single letter options, spaces are irrelevant.  This is not a Linux thing but is true on all Unix systems.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question in the title which I interpret as meaning: report the whitespace-delimited words that do not start with an alphanumeric or underscore (the `\w` in some regexp engines), you could do with GNU `grep` provided it's built with PCRE support:

```
grep -Po '(?<!\S)[^\w\s]\S*'
```

That is a character other (`^`) than a word one (`\w`) or whitespace one (`\s`) provided it's not preceded (`(?<!...)`) by a non-whitespace (`\S`), and followed by any number (`*`) of non-whitespace (`\S`).

Which on your input returns:

```
-a
--verbose
```

Comment: The closest ERE equivalent is `grep -Eo '(^|[[:space:]])[^[:space:][:alnum:]]+\<[^[:space:]]+'`

Answer (score 0):

With `GNU grep` you  an approach this problem by means of `positive lookarounds` as shown:

```
 $ grep -oP '(?:(?!\h)\W)+\w+' inp
```

To be read as, from where i stand in the string, i see a nonword follow a word. But, that nonword precludes any whitespace.

Output:

```
 -a
 --verbose
```